# Dual Franka Moveit Configuration not working with real robot

Tags: ros, moveit

I am working with a package configured with moveit setup assistant starting from the example of a dual arm+hand URDF file provided in franka decsription (panda robot). My goal is to program through moveit two franka robots. Following the Moveit Setup Assistant documentations:

1. I generated the collision matrix
2. I added a virtual joint, called "world", with child link "base"
3. I added both "panda_1_arm" and "panda_2_arm" with respectively panda_1_joint1 to panda_2_joint8 and panda_2_joint1 to panda_2_joint8 and hand_1 and hand_2 as planning groups
4. I created an arm_position_controller of type position_controllers/JointPositionController with all the joints from panda_1_joint1 to panda_1_joint8 and panda_2_joint1 to panda_2_joint8

Then, I added the following controllers.yaml file:
[controllers.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVTIJ.png)

However, when I run both

```
roslaunch <package_name> move_group.launch, and

roslaunch franka_control franka_combined_control.launch robot_ips:="{panda_1/robot_ip: 172.16.1.3, panda_2/robot_ip: 172.16.0.2}"
```

I get the following errors:

```
[FATAL] [1646741944.689482176]: Parameter '~moveit_controller_manager' not specified. This is needed to identify the plugin to use for interacting with controllers. No paths can be executed.

[ WARN] [1646741949.746722512]: Waiting for arm_position_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up

[ WARN] [1646741955.746841732]: Waiting for arm_position_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up

[ERROR] [1646741961.746962763]: Action client not connected
```

Could someone show me the solution to these errors?